# setUseWideViewPort(true) addes unnecessary scrolling in android

Tags: android, webview

For webview i am applying `setUseWideViewPort(true)` property, then even though body is less (fix in screen), it is displaying the Horizontal and vertical scrolling.

How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
>   webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);